# How do I check whether squares of certain numbers in one list are in the second

Tags: python, arrays, return, python-3.6

So, I've stumbled upon a problem during my codewars practise and i'm currently stuck on how to actually check for squares in another list.

I passed some tests, but when I actually try to submit it, it raises certain errors, and tests come back False.

```
import math
def comp(array1, array2):
    **if array1 == []:
        return False
    if array2 == []:
        return False
    for i in range(len(array1)):
        promenljiva = array1[i * i]
        if promenljiva in array2:
            return True
            break

    for j in range(len(array2) - 1):
        promenljiva_1 = math.sqrt(array2[j])
        if promenljiva_1 not in array1:
            return False
        elif promenljiva_1 != array1[0]:
            return False
            break
```

This is my code, so if someone can please assist me on this, I would be very happy! :)
P.S. Promenljiva is actually just a serbian term for variable :)

Comment: `any(x*x in array2 for x in array1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return True if all of the items**2 in array1 are in array 2. Otherwise, it will return False. However, it will still return True if there are additional values in array2.

```
def comp(array1, array2):
    results = []
    for i in array1:
        if i*i in array2:
            results.append(True)
        else:
            results.append(False)
    if False in results:   #if any squares are not in array2, return False
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stackoverflow. I don't know much about python (I'm still learning it), but I think it would be better if you could add some explanation as to what your answer does. If it isn't necessary then just ignore this comment :)

Comment: Listen, I think the problem is very easy to deal with, I'm just a little confused since i'm only 18 and starting to code :( The code is supposed to check whether square numbers of array1 are in array2, Therefore, if they are not it should return False. For example: if array = [2, 4, 6], and array2 = [4, 16, 36], it should return True. If for example, array1=[2, 4, 6], and array2 = [4, 16, 81], it should return False. Dont know if you got it :(

Comment: Dimitrije, I modified the my code to be in compliance with your given test cases. Also, the order of the squares is irrelevant in my code so long as the square exists in array2 (Ex: if array1= [2,6,4] and array2= [4,16,36] it will still return True).